# Set background image in asp.net core mvc

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

I have created a folder inside wwwroot, called Media. I'm trying to set a background image with css like this:

```
<body style='background-image: url("~/Media/background.png")'>
```

But the background does not appear.

However, if I try to put is as a image it works:

```
<img src="~/Media/background.png" />
```

So, how do I handle background images?

Comment: Is the server does not send the imag?! Inspect the code from the browser and see if it received from the server or not ?

Comment: ASP.NET's Tag-Helpers for resolving `~/` do not work inside `style=""` attributes, but you can use `@Url.Content()`.

Comment: Bryan: a quick reminder about spelling. Would you please use a spell-checker?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
<body style="background-image: url(../Media/background.png)">
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe: try to use url of image instead of relative path.

In That case I suppose `https://yourdomain/media/background.png' could do the trick.